# Comparing struct pointers, casting away members, and UB

Tags: c, casting, undefined-behavior, void-pointers, strict-aliasing

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct { int first; float second; } type;

    type whole = { 1, 2.0 };
    void * vp = &whole;

    struct { int first; } * shorn = vp;
    printf("values: %d, %d\n", ((type *)vp)->first, shorn->first);
    if (vp == shorn)
        printf("ptrs compare the same\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is the pointer equality comparison UB?
2. Regarding the "shearing" away of the `second` member on the line that initializes `shorn`: is it valid C to cast away struct members like this and then dereference the manipulated pointer to access the remaining member?

Comment: Dereferencing the first member should be OK as by definition the address of a struct is equal to the address of it's first element. But if there is more than one remaining element I'm not sure if  there could be different paddings in both structs whaht would mak dereferencing invalid

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: Under the interpretation of the Standard used by clang and gcc, the aliasing rules that would forbid using a pointer of one structure type to access members of another take priority over any other part of the Standard that would otherwise define the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section **6.2.5 Types** paragraph **28** of the C standard says:

> [...] All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. [...]

Section **6.3.2.3 Pointers** paragraph **1** says:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

And paragraph **7** says:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned<sup>68)</sup> for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. [...]

And footnote **68** says:

> In general, the concept "correctly aligned" is transitive: if a pointer to type A is correctly aligned for a pointer to type B, which in turn is correctly aligned for a pointer to type C, then a pointer to type A is correctly aligned for a pointer to type C.

Because all pointers to structure types have the same representation, the conversions between pointers to `void` and pointers to structure types must be the same for all pointers to structure types. So it seems that a pointer to structure type A could be converted by a cast operator directly to a pointer to structure type B without an intermediate conversion to a pointer to `void` as long as the pointer is "correctly aligned" for structure type B. (This may be a weak argument.)

The question remains when, in the case of two structure types A and B where the initial sequence of structure type A consists of all the members of structure type B, a pointer to structure type A is guaranteed to be correctly aligned for structure type B (the reverse is obviously not guaranteed). As far as I can tell, the C standard makes no such guarantee. So strictly speaking, a pointer to the larger structure type A might not be correctly aligned for the smaller structure type B, and if it is not, the behavior is undefined. For a "sane" compiler, the larger structure type A would not have weaker alignment than the smaller structure type B, but for an "insane" compiler, that might not be the case.

---

Regarding the second question about accessing members of the truncated (shorter) structure using the pointer derived from the full (longer) structure, then as long as the pointer is correctly aligned for the shorter structure (see above for why that might not be true for an "insane" compiler), and as long as strict aliasing rules are avoided (for example, by going through an intermediate pointer to void in an intermediate external function call across compilation unit boundaries), then accessing the members through the pointer to the shorter structure type should be perfectly fine. There is a special guarantee for that when objects of both structure types appear as members of the same union type. Section **6.3.2.3 Structure and union members** paragraph **6** says:

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union
> object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union
> is visible. Two structures share a *common initial sequence* if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial members.

However, since the offsets of members within a structure type does not depend on whether an object of the structure type appears in a union type or not, the above implies that any structures with a common initial sequence of members will have those common members at the same offsets within their respective structure types.

Comment: Although many implementations will usefully refrain from applying the "strict aliasing rules" in cases where a pointer is cast through `void*` and/or passed across compilation-unit boundaries, nothing in the Standard requires such forbearance, and some compiler writers view such forbearance as needlessly foregone optimization rather than useful behavior.  On the other hand, the Standard doesn't even require that pointers to struct members be meaningfully usable to access the enclosing structures without going through character types or `memcpy`, but instead relies upon implementations to...

Comment: ...use some formerly-common sense.

Answer (score 5):

Comparing two pointers with `==` when one is a `void *` is well defined.

Section 6.5.9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the equality operator `==` says the following:

> *2* One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> - **one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`**; or
> - one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant
>
> ...
>
> *5* Otherwise, at least one operand is a pointer.  If one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant, the null pointer
> constant is converted to the type of the pointer.  **If one  operand
> is  a  pointer  to  an  object  type  and  the  other  is  a  pointer
> to  a  qualified  or unqualified version of `void`, the former is
> converted to the type of the latter.**

The usage of `shorn->first` works because a pointer to a struct can be converted to a pointer to its first member.  For both `type` and the unnamed struct type their first member is an `int` so it works out.

Comment: Thanks @dbush (and also for your answer to my other question).  So casting away struct members like this is ok, and dereferencing such manipulated pointers to access the remaining member isn't going to get me fired?

Comment: But is the initialisation of `shorn` by `vp` valid? This answer kind of talks around this issue.

Comment: Hi @KonradRudolph: yes, I think that's what I'm trying to ask, whether the use of such converted pointers is valid?  I've edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

In the language the C89 Standard was written to describe, it was well established that if two structures share a common initial sequence, a pointer to either may be cast to the other and used to inspect members of that common initial sequence.  Code which relied upon this was commonplace and not considered even remotely controversial.

In the interest of optimization, the authors of the C99 Standard deliberately allowed compilers to assume that structures of different types won't alias *in cases where such assumption would be useful for their customers*.  Because there are many good means by which implementations could recognize cases where such assumptions would be needlessly break what had been perfectly good code, and because they the authors of the Standard expected that compiler writers would make a bona fide effort to behave in ways useful to the programmers using their products, the Standard doesn't mandate any *particular* means of making such distinctions.  Instead, it regards the ability to support constructs that had been universally supported as a "quality of implementation" issue, which would be reasonable if compiler writers made a bona fide effort to treat it as such.

Unfortunately, some compiler writers who aren't interested in selling their products to paying customers have taken the Standard's failure to mandate useful behavior as an invitation to behave in needlessly useless fashion.  Code which relies upon Common Initial Sequence guarantees can thus not be meaningfully processed by clang or gcc without using either non-standard syntax or disabling type-based aliasing entirely.

Comment: Thanks @supercat.  By "disabling type-based aliasing", do you mean using -fno-strict-aliasing?

Comment: @textral: Yup.  In most kinds of programs where CIS guarantees would be useful, any context--*drawn narrowly or broadly*--in which two kinds of structure are used to reference storage via the CIS guarantees would contain code that would visibly derive a reference to one type from a reference to the other, or derive both from a reference to a common type.  If a function is being processed in isolation, types used by the caller would not be used within the context of the function.  If a function is being optimized in relation to its caller, any type derivations in the caller...

Comment: ...would be performed in the context of the function.  What's needed is effectively that compilers' effort to consolidate accesses to unrelated objects be balanced with bona fide efforts to notice object relationships.  The less effort compilers put into the former, the less they would need to put into the latter.  I think the authors of the Standard expected that if compilers tried balance those things, they'd handle more cases better than the Committee would be able to by writing rigid rules.  As it is, though, gcc and clang maximize the effort into the former; while minimizing the latter.

Comment: @supercat Well, yeah.  "Look at this kewl optimization I can do if I assume these pointers can never alias!  It can save an entire 14 nanoseconds when the moon is full, the wind is from the southwest, and in Norway the lemmings are migrating!"  When all you know is writing compiler code for a mature 40-year-old language, in between the once-a-decade standard revisions you [egest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egestion) solutions in search of problems.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: More to the point, optimizations can offer 90% improvements in execution speed, if one doesn't care about behavior in situations not mandated by the Standard.  If such optimizations break the code, that means the programmer should have written the program in such a way as to allow for the 90% performance in improvement, even if the previous code happened to be the most efficient possible code *that actually performed the required task*.

Comment: @supercat: out of curiosity, what's the "non-standard syntax" you refer to that allows clang/gcc to "meaningfuly process" code that relies on CIS guarantees?

Comment: @textral: The syntax  `typedef type1 __attribute__((__may_alias__)) type2;` will cause `type2` to behave as a synonym for `type1`, except that objects of type `type2` will be presumed capable of aliasing all objects of all other types.