# What's the name of this technique and does it violate strict-aliasing rules or invoke UB?

Tags: c, closures, undefined-behavior, currying, strict-aliasing

I have come up with some code which makes use of a self-referential struct (the 1st element of the struct is a pointer to a function that takes an instance of the struct as its one and only argument).

It has been useful for passing disparate routines to another to invoke because the invoking routine doesn't need to know the exact argument makeup of the passed routines (see the `process_string` call sites in the code below).  The passed/invoked routines themselves are responsible for unpacking (casting) the args in a way meaningful to them.

At the bottom of this post is some sample code making use of this technique.  It produces the following output when compiled with `gcc -std=c99 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`:

```
nread: 5
vals[0]: 0.000000
vals[1]: 0.000000
vals[2]: 0.000000
vals[3]: 78.900000
vals[4]: 32.100000
vals[5]: 65.400000
vals[6]: 87.400000
vals[7]: 65.000000
12.3 12.3
34.5 34.5
56.7 56.7
78.9 78.9
32.1 32.1
65.4 65.4
87.4 87.4
65.0 65.0
```

---

My questions are:

1. What is the name of this technique?  As you can see from the code, I've been using the name **functor** but I'm not sure that is correct.  It looks a little like a **closure** but I don't think it is since it just points to it's arguments rather than carrying along copies of them.
2. Does the code violate the strict-aliasing rule?
3. Does the code invoke Undefined Behavior?

---

And now for the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct functor_s functor_t;
typedef int (func_t)(functor_t);
struct functor_s { func_t * _0; void * _1; void * _2; void * _3; void * _4; };

void process_string(char * buf, int skip, functor_t ftor) {
    for (int i = skip; i < 8; ++i) {
        ftor._4 = buf + i*5;
        ftor._3 = &i;
        (void)ftor._0(ftor);
    }
}

int scan_in_double(functor_t in) {
    // unpack the args
    const char * p = in._4;
    int offset = *(int*)in._3;
    int * count = in._1;
    double * dest = in._2;

    // do the work
    return *count += sscanf(p, "%lg", dest + offset);
}

int print_repeated(functor_t in) {
    // unpack the args
    const char * p = in._4;
    
    // do the work
    char tmp[10] = {0};
    sscanf(p, "%s", tmp);
    printf("%s %s\n", tmp, tmp);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char line[50] = "12.3 34.5 56.7 78.9 32.1 65.4 87.4 65.0";

    int nread = 0;
    double vals[8] = {0};

    functor_t ftor1 = { scan_in_double, &nread, vals };
    process_string(line, 3, ftor1);

    // check that it worked properly
    printf("nread: %d\n", nread);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        printf("vals[%d]: %f\n", i, vals[i]);
    }
    
    functor_t ftor2 = { print_repeated };
    process_string(line, 0, ftor2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT:  In response to @supercat's suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63332205/1206102), I reworked my example to pass a double-indirect function pointer (which incidentally made the self-referentiality unecessary) and added an extra case: scanning in ints.  The ability to scan in different types better illustrates the need for a void* arg in both the functor struct & the function pointer sig.  Here's the new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (func_t)(int offset, const char * src, void * extra);
typedef struct { func_t * func; void * data; } ftor_t;
typedef struct { int * count; double * dest; } extra_dbl_t;
typedef struct { int * count; int * dest; } extra_int_t;

void process_string(char * buf, int skip, func_t ** func) {
    ftor_t * ftor = (ftor_t*)func;  // <---- strict-alias violation? or UB?
    for (int i = skip; i < 8; ++i) {
        (void)ftor->func(i, buf+i*5, ftor->data);
    }
}

int scan_in_double(int offset, const char * src, void * extra) {
    extra_dbl_t * in = extra;
    return *in->count += sscanf(src, "%lg", in->dest + offset);
}

int scan_in_int(int offset, const char * src, void * extra) {
    extra_int_t * in = extra;
    return *in->count += sscanf(src, "%d", in->dest + offset);
}

int print_repeated(int offset, const char * src, void * extra) {
    // extra not used
    char tmp[10] = {0};
    sscanf(src, "%s", tmp);
    printf("%s %s\n", tmp, tmp);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // contrived strings to make the simplistic +5 in process_string work
    // (the real process_string would use whitespace to non-whitespace
    // transition)
    char dbl_line[50] = "12.3 34.5 56.7 78.9 32.1 65.4 87.4 65.0";
    char int_line[50] = "1234 3456 5678 7890 3210 6543 8743 6501";

    int n_ints_read = 0;
    int int_vals[8] = {0};

    extra_int_t int_data = { .count=&n_ints_read, .dest=int_vals };
    ftor_t ftor0 = { scan_in_int, &int_data };
    process_string(int_line, 0, &ftor0.func);

    // check that it worked properly
    printf("n_ints_read: %d\n", n_ints_read);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        printf("int_vals[%d]: %d\n", i, int_vals[i]);
    }
    
    int n_dbls_read = 0;
    double dbl_vals[8] = {0};

    extra_dbl_t dbl_data = { .count=&n_dbls_read, .dest=dbl_vals };
    ftor_t ftor1 = { scan_in_double, &dbl_data };
    process_string(dbl_line, 3, &ftor1.func);

    // check that it worked properly
    printf("n_dbls_read: %d\n", n_dbls_read);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        printf("dbl_vals[%d]: %f\n", i, dbl_vals[i]);
    }
    
    ftor_t ftor2 = { print_repeated };  // no extra data req'd
    process_string(dbl_line, 0, &ftor2.func);

    return 0;
}
```

But if I accept a ptr to the struct/functor instead:

```
void process_string(char * buf, int skip, ftor_t * ftor) {
    for (int i = skip; i < 8; ++i) {
        (void)ftor->func(i, buf+i*5, ftor->data);
    }
}
```

And change the call site to:

```
process_string(dbl_line, 0, &ftor2);  // not &ftor2.func
```

Then there's no pointer casting in process_string(), and therefore no strict-alias violation.  I think.

In both cases, the new output is:

```
n_ints_read: 8
int_vals[0]: 1234
int_vals[1]: 3456
int_vals[2]: 5678
int_vals[3]: 7890
int_vals[4]: 3210
int_vals[5]: 6543
int_vals[6]: 8743
int_vals[7]: 6501
n_dbls_read: 5
dbl_vals[0]: 0.000000
dbl_vals[1]: 0.000000
dbl_vals[2]: 0.000000
dbl_vals[3]: 78.900000
dbl_vals[4]: 32.100000
dbl_vals[5]: 65.400000
dbl_vals[6]: 87.400000
dbl_vals[7]: 65.000000
12.3 12.3
34.5 34.5
56.7 56.7
78.9 78.9
32.1 32.1
65.4 65.4
87.4 87.4
65.0 65.0
```

Comment: @chux: I forgot to add `return 0;`

Comment: except the nitpicked typo (return value is not used so there is no UB) I do not see any problems in your code. I do not know what function pointers are for in this example but only access it via the char pointer.

Comment: For me its implies the warning level like `'-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wconversion'` was not employed.  Removing distracting warnings brings clarity to the post.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree @chux: using the extra flags only produces a couple of "missing initializer for field ‘_n’ of ‘functor_t’" warnings (where `n` is 3 for the `ftor1` initialization, and 1 for `ftor2`'s initialization)

Comment: Identifiers that begin with `_` are reserved for specific purposes only. You should not use such identifiers.

Comment: Why do you think this is not closure? It is carrying the pointers by value

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: because it's the objects being pointed to, not the pointers themselves, that have significance for the function (pointer) in the 1st struct element

Comment: @textral The way I see it is that the function actually cares about a pointer (and then later deferences it as you would with any pointer). So it is still a closure with different types for the captured values. I guess at this point we would be just arguing about nomenclature . .

Comment: What @Ajay said: it's a closure - you're just passing some pointer arguments to the function, instead of passing them directly.

Comment: @psmears & AjayBrahmakshatriya: won't closures still function properly when invoked after their referenced arguments go out of scope?  My "thing" will crash in that case.  (But you've made me doubt my earlier certainty so I've edited the question to reflect that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. What is the name of this technique?

Obfuscation.

It has similarities with [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) and with [argument currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), but I wouldn't characterize it as either one.

It also has similarities with object-oriented program structure and practice, but the focus on intentionally hiding the argument types has no particular place in that regime.

And there is a hint of [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), too.

Overall, though, it's just an over-abstracted mess.

> It has been useful for passing disparate routines to another to invoke
> because the invoking routine doesn't need to know the exact argument
> makeup of the passed routines

I think you're fooling yourself.

Your `functor_t` indeed doesn't carry any information about the types that the parameters need to have, and it places only an upper bound on the number of them, but that's nothing to cheer about.  The user of each instance still needs to know those things in order to use the object correctly, and the functor hides them not only from the user, but also from the compiler, such that neither one can easily check whether the user has set up the parameters correctly.  The user furthermore does not benefit from any of the default argument conversions that happen in a direct function call, so they need to ensure exact type matching.

The only way I see something like this making sense is as more or less a pure callback interface, where the same user packages both the function to call and the arguments to pass to it -- or some specific ones of them, at least -- into an object, then stores or passes that off for some other function to call later.  But such callback interfaces are usually structured differently, without including the function in the object alongside the arguments, and they do not go out of their way to hide data types.

> 2. Does the code violate the strict-aliasing rule?

Not inherently, but strict-aliasing violations will arise if pointers to the wrong types of objects are stored in a functor's parameter members, and the functor's function is then called.

> 3. Does the code invoke Undefined Bahavior?

Not inherently, but yes in the event of a strict-aliasing violation.

Comment: Ah yes, **argument currying**, I hadn't thought of that one, but yes you're right.

Comment: *"the same user packages both the function to call and the arguments to pass it"* -- yes that's how I'm using it, mainly to DRY out my code.  Is there a better way to write a "dispatch" routine that can execute any given function and its arg list, with some of the args populated by the dispatcher, in a way that preserves static type-checking?  (Maybe that should be a new SO question in its own right?)

Comment: No, @textral, what I described is *not* how you are using it, at least not in the examples presented in the question.  Your main function is assigning the function to the functor, and passing it to `process_string`, which assigns the arguments to it.  I recognize that you're enamored of this invention, but, frankly, it's perverse.  I appreciate the pursuit of DRYness, but if that's the motivation then the code goes to unreasonable, counterproductive extremes.

Comment: "Is there a better way to write a "dispatch" routine that can execute any given function and its arg list [...]?"  There is *no* good way to do that in C, including the one presented in the question.  And I consider that of no account, because the problem you propose is overly general.  C callback interfaces that allow the callback provider to give some of the arguments generally specify a specific prototype for the callback function, and allow for *one* user-provided argument of type `void *`.  That's adequately general because the user-provided data can be a struct with arbitrary members.

Comment: Laurent Dami's curry design (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.585.1035&rep=rep1&type=pdf) has better encapsulation for passing to external users/code.  I'm still reading thru it but it doesn't look non-standard (using gcc's nested function extension).  But it suffers the same lack of type-checking as mine.  How would you rate Dami's mechanism, @JohnBollinger?

Comment: @textral, I would agree with Dami that the limitations of that mechanism -- high runtime cost, lack of type checking -- make it suitable only for sparing use.  Moreover, any implementation of those basic ideas built on top of the existing language is definitely nonstandard, because it depends on converting an object pointer to a function pointer, which C does not support.

Comment: As for GCC nested functions, (i) they are non-standard (being an *extension*), therefore they cannot provide a means to implement Dami's function currying ideas in a standard-conforming way; (ii) GCC nested functions can access the host function's variables only until the host function exits, which is not sufficient for general function currying; and (iii) to the extent that they are applicable and you are willing to rely on them, GCC nested functions are all-around better than Dami's proposal, so there's no point in using nested functions to implement Dami's ideas.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Another issue is that the semantics of gcc's nested functions are not achievable in all execution environments, and reliance upon them may result in code designs that could not be made to work well in some environments without substantial rework.

Comment: Good observation, @supercat, agreed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Implementations whose code address space is larger than the data address space could accommodate round-trip conversions by having a table, in data space, of the machine addresses of all functions whose address is taken, and having function pointers hold offsets within that table.  I find it somewhat curious that such designs aren't used more often, especially on compilers for 8-bit platforms, since even programs that would use up 128K of code space would be seldom have more than 63 functions of any particular type *whose address is taken*, and invoking such funcs via table...

Comment: ...would be faster than trying to load all three bytes of a 24-bit pointer.

Comment: @supercat, when I say that object pointers cannot be converted to function pointers, I mean it in the sense that the Standard uses the term "convert".  That is relevant here because Dami's currying implementation involves dynamically building function implementations in memory (which can be done only via an object pointer), and then providing a function pointer pointing to that memory, which requires converting the object pointer into a function pointer.  I don't see how the table-based approach you describe could be applied to that scenario.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The ability to execute code from writable storage is a separate issue.  The Standard's normal limitations on conversion stem from the possibility that code and data spaces may be of different sizes.  My preferred approach for passing methods is to use a double-indirect pointer, which is something that implementations could automatically support, though method pointers would be incompatible with "normal" function pointers.

Comment: @supercat, the question about ability to execute code from writable storage is not my point.  The standard defines type conversions that may be performed.  Object pointers can be converted to other object pointers, but there is no defined conversion from object pointer to function pointer.  One can convert indirectly through an integer intermediate, provided that there is a suitable integer type available, but the standard has nothing to say about what might happen if one attempted to perform a function call via that function.

Comment: To put it more briefly, standard C does not provide for programs to dynamically construct functions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: If C had a means of designating structure types for which use of function-call syntax on a pointer to such a structure should be processed as a function call via the structure's first member, with the address of the structure passed as an argument before all the others, then it would be possible to have code would use pointers to such structures in a fashion syntactically compatible with use of ordinary functions, and it would be possible for portable code to construct method pointers that could encapsulate arbitrary data.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a pointer to the first member of the method structure (i.e. a double-indirect function pointer), rather than passing the structure by value.  This will avoid the need for any of the code which needs to pass through or invoke that method pointer to care about anything other than the fact that the structure leads off with a function pointer.  The actual function should receive as an argument (probably the first one) a copy of the pointer to the structure, which it can then use to retrieve any other parameters it needs.

If you want to pass around a function-pointer-plus-arguments structure rather than using a double-indirect pointer, I'd suggest having a structure contain a function pointer and a `void*` rather than trying to have the pass-through code care about anything beyond that.

Here's a demo of what I have in mind:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void (*streamOutFunc)(void *, void const *dat, uint32_t len);
struct StringStream
{
    streamOutFunc func;
    char *dest;
    uint32_t size,len,totlen;
};
void putStringStreamFunc(void *param, void const *dat, uint32_t len)
{
    struct StringStream *it = param;
    uint32_t maxLen = it->size - it->len;
    uint32_t newTot = it->totlen + len;
    if (newTot < len)
        newTot = -1;
    if (len > maxLen)
        len = maxLen;
    memcpy(it->dest+it->len, dat, len);
    it->totlen = newTot;
    it->len += len;

}
struct FileStream
{
    streamOutFunc func;
    FILE *f;
};
void putFileStreamFunc(void *param, void const *dat, uint32_t len)
{
    struct FileStream *it = param;
    fwrite(dat, len, 1, it->f);
}
void outputSomething(streamOutFunc *stream, void const *dat, uint32_t len)
{
    (*stream)(stream, "Message: [", (sizeof "Message: [")-1);
    (*stream)(stream, dat, len);
    (*stream)(stream, "]\n", (sizeof "]\n")-1);
}
int main(void)
{
    char msgBuff[20];
    struct StringStream myStringStream =
      {putStringStreamFunc, msgBuff, sizeof msgBuff, 0, 0};
    
    outputSomething(&myStringStream.func, "TESTING 12345", (sizeof "TESTING 12345")-1);

    struct FileStream myFileStream =
      {putFileStreamFunc, stdout};
    outputSomething(&myFileStream.func, msgBuff, myStringStream.len);

}
```

Comment: Thanks @supercat: if I just pass the double-indirect function pointer, I would have to cast it to a ptr to the struct in order to pass it as the argument to the function... would that violate the strict-aliasing rule?  (This relates closely to another question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63175051/1206102)

Comment: @textral: The function should accept a `void*` and do the casting itself, since it will know the actual type of the object it's expecting.  If `processWoozle()` expects a pointer to a `WOOZLE_PARAMS`, parameter-building code that isn't using type `WOOZLE_PARAMS` shouldn't store the address of `processWoozle()` in them.

Comment: I reworked my example to pass a double-indirect function pointer, see my edit near the bottom of my original post.  I may not have understood exactly what you meant as I couldn't get rid of the function-ptr-cast-to-object-ptr so I may still be in violation of strict-aliasing, or even into UB territory.  Still, it works & looks far better than it did!  But see the further commentary below the full 2nd example: if I pass a ptr to the functor instead, I do away with the cast entirely and avoid strict-aliasing issues.  I think this is what you meant by your 2nd paragraph in your answer, right?

Comment: @textral: See my demo.

Comment: Ah, I see!  You're "casting" the function pointer to an object pointer thru a void* intermediary (the 1st function arg) without an explicit cast.  Nice!  I guess @JohnBollinger would argue this is UB?  Or implementation-defined?

Comment: @textral: What's being converted to `void*` is not the function pointer, but the address of the *object* in which the function pointer is stored.

Comment: Wow!  Ok, right: the address of the func ptr is *equivalent to* the address of the object containing it by virtue of the fact that the former is the 1st element of the latter (I believe this is explicitly stated in the standard).  That's brilliant.  By making the func ptr the 1st element of a struct, you force the compiler to treat the func ptr address the same as it would treat an object address, including allowing the roundtrip-conversion-via-void*-intermediate rule.

Comment: BTW, I accepted John's answer because he did well to answer all the questions I posed, especially the 1st question of identifying the technique(s) in use.  Your's was more helpful in improving my solution but, unfortunately, I did not pose that as a question in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

For a definition of functor see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor. This does not seem fitting here.

Essentially this is how you can implement object oriented programming in C.

You see this technique in the Linux kernel to describe device drivers. The driver descriptor contains pointers to functions and some additional data, e.g:

```
    static struct platform_driver meson_rng_driver = { 
        .probe  = meson_rng_probe, // a function
        .driver = {
                .name = "meson-rng",
                .of_match_table = meson_rng_of_match,
        },
    };
```

Linux collect these driver descriptors in linker generated lists.

In object oriented programming the structure definition (here struct platform_driver) represents an interface and the structure with the actual function pointers a class and the functions pointed to the methods of the class. The data fields contain the class level variables.

There is no undefined behavior involved. There is no violation of strict aliasing.

Comment: This answer doesn't address any of the three questions asked

Comment: It answers how to call this technique.